# There should be some common piece of hardware /firmware or software among different devices, isn't it?

Tags: memory-hardware

There should be some common piece of hardware /firmware or software among different devices,  isn't it? like among PCs,  PlayStation,  Xbox, Android phones or feature phones from pre 2008 era etc. Is there or not?  like something exactly the same,  some chip,  transistors,  anything??

Comment: Where do I ask this question?

Comment: [Science Fiction & Fantasy@SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/)? (SCR) Most gadgets seem to work with [*elec-trickery*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catweazle#Summary).

Answer (score 0):

All the devices you mentioned have a processor that is built using integrated chips made of silicon.

- The fundamental building block of these digital chips is the transistor. Moore's law mentions the growth rate of transistors because this is common across integrated circuits.
- Transistors are further used to build NAND gates that is used to construct logic. If you are interested in learning more about this, you can check out [nand2tetris](https://www.nand2tetris.org/) which is a course aimed at going through different levels of abstraction in modern computing starting from the very basic level